# Найти минимальный положительный элемент массива с помощью рекурсии

Tags: java, рекурсия

Так звучит задача.
*Создать рекурсивный метод, реализующий один из следующих алгоритмов обработки массива. Массив заполняется случайными образом числами от -256 до +256.*

Пол задачи я уже решил, осталось понять какое условие нужно написать(и куда), чтобы отрицательные элементы массива не учитывались.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[7];
    for(int j =0;j<array.length; j++) {
        array[j] = ((int) (Math.random() * 513) - 256);
        System.out.println(array[j]);
    }
    int minPositive = LoopImitation(array,0);
    System.out.println(minPositive);
}
public static int LoopImitation(int[] elements, int index) {

    if (index == elements.length - 1) {
        return elements[index];
    }

    int min = LoopImitation(elements, index + 1);

        if (elements[index] < min) {
            return elements[index];
        } else
            return min;
}
}
```

Comment: Почему не нужно учитывать отрицательные элементы?

Comment: Задание: "Найти минимальный Положительный элемент массива с помощью рекурсии"
Сейчас программа находи самый минимальный, а мне нужно, чтобы он был ещё и положительным.

Comment: Вы всегда пишете формулировку задачи в разных местах? Половина в заголовке, половина в тексте? Добавьте в if проверку на положительность и все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public static int LoopImitation(int[] elements, int index) {
        if (index == elements.length) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        return Math.min(elements[index] < 1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : elements[index], 
                LoopImitation(elements, index + 1));
    }
```

Вот только непонятно что возвращать, если положительных элементов не будет. В данном случае возвращается Integer.MAX_VALUE.